# Automating Enter keypress not working for Linux Mint 15

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, automation

I've got this post installation script I made for users of Linux Mint 14 (and also usable on Ubuntu 12.10) and now I'm testing it for Linux Mint 15 and the 'echo -ne "\n" | sudo add-apt-repository ppa:some-ppa-to-add' command isn't working on Linux Mint 15, but still works on Mint 14. I want to update this script for the new version of Linux Mint.

Here's a link to my post install scipt: [The Minty Developer](https://github.com/villimagg/The-Minty-Developer/blob/master/minty-devinstaller.sh)

The output for Mint 14 looks like this:

```
$ echo -ne "\n" | sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apt-fast/stable
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
 This PPA contains tested (stable) builds of apt-fast.
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~apt-fast/+archive/stable
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpddxueh/secring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key CA8DA16B from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpddxueh/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key CA8DA16B: public key "Launchpad PPA for apt-fast" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
```

And here's the output on Mint 15:

```
$ echo -ne "\n" | sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apt-fast/stable
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
This PPA contains tested (stable) builds of apt-fast.
More info: https://launchpad.net/~apt-fast/+archive/stable
```

And that's it. Nothing happens.
I've also tested doing just echo | ppa:some-ppa-to-add and it's the same results.

Can anyone help me figure out how to make this line of code/command work so that the script can be updated for those interested in using it with a new version of their system?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `add-apt-repository --yes` but you are overriding a system-wide security policy by answering that question.

You don't say who the user is; I would be annoyed if your script did that for me, but I'm not a typical end-user.  I just looked at your script, and it is conversational enough generally. If it said something like

> I'm going to add these packages from reasonably trustworthy sources and set them up so they will automatically update, etc., etc.

it would be more polite.

**Added**

There is an undocumented feature in `add-apt-repository` which allows you to override the question programmatically:

```
if (sys.stdin.isatty() and
  not "FORCE_ADD_APT_REPOSITORY" in os.environ):
    if options.remove:
        print(_("Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel removing it"))
            else:
        print(_("Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it"))
        sys.stdin.readline()
```

Thus the bash sequence

```
export FORCE_ADD_APT_REPOSITORY=force
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
sudo add-apt-repository ...
```

should stop the questions. It will still show the noise

```
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
 Sublime Text 2 packages - the .deb will automatically download the 
 latest build from http://www.sublimetext.com/dev or beta from
 http://www.sublimetext.com/2 (Adobe Flash Player installer - style).

More info and feedback: 
http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/sublime-text-2-ubuntu-ppa.html
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/03/sublime-text-2-ppa-separate-development.html
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/sublime-text-2
```

but that is put on stdout so should be able to be sent to `> /dev/null` with errors still appearing on stderr.

Comment: Thank you I will test it out and I will definitely add something like that to the script :)

Comment: I started looking through the suite of apt-* scripts and the `--yes` flag documentation applies only to one question about fixing up `lp:` repositories. I've not yet found the place where it asks about adding keys, but my will is strong...

Comment: @VilliMagg I found it, see **Added**